# Setting up node.js with a typescript project

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-2013

I currently have a typescript project in Web express 2013 which works. I want to add a nodejs server side functionality.

In my ts folder I have my game logic and now I added this file Server.Ts

```
///<reference path="d.ts/node.d.ts" />

var url = require('url'),
    path = require('path'),
    http = require('http')
        .createServer(function (request, response) {
            var dest = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
            console.log('url [' + dest + '] requested');
            response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            response.end('Hello World');
        }).listen(8080);
```

What is the next steps to get this steps working and do you think its a bad idea combinging the server and Client ts in the one project?

Answer (score 0):

no, its not a bad approach to have server and client side code in the same project, but you should structure things into client(jquery etc.), server(node.js etc) and shared code (config, models, etc.). But if you've got a big client base, makeing it a separate git project may make sense as well.

To make it easier to develop for node, use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/). And to easily pass your transcode your .ts to a .js file, use [a grunt task like grunt-typescript](https://github.com/k-maru/grunt-typescript)

Comment: thanks, but vs 2013 automatically generates the js files. Do you know the best way to get the ts project running with node?

Comment: since VS2013 as you state converts the .ts files to .js files in your DestinationDirectory X, you need to `cd X` and then run `node yourStartScript.js`

Comment: @japrescott thanks but can you do this from VS2013 without going the cmd route?

Comment: ?! idk how to execute a node script under windows (->linux). but since this is a node.js question, I hope you do know